# Modify files in for loop

Tags: for-loop, ssh, sed

I upload to host list.txt with list of infected files. It looks like this:

```
file1.php
file2.php
cat/file3.php
cat/subcat/file4.php
```

Infected files are modifed in 1st line only. So I run `for` loop. This loop has to change whole first line that has malicious code to `<?php`.

```
for file in $(cat list.txt); do sed -i '1s/.*/<?php/' *.php; done
```

The problem is that the loop seems to change files only in first folder (file1 and file2). The files in subdfolders are not changed. Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in the sed command you are not really using the variable defined in the loop.
Try

```
for file in $(cat list.txt); do sed -i '1s/.*/<?php/' $file; done
```

Comment: Works GREAT! Thanks gile.

Comment: P.S. Is there a way to run this loop in all folders except one, eg. /user

Comment: for file in $(egrep -v 'user/' list.txt); do sed -i '1s/.*/<?php/' $file; done